# Aws Security Hub - createmembers boto3 returns the requested account under UnprocessedAccounts in the response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Trying to create a new member (random other account) to my security hub in aws.
for some reason the request returns some of the accounts as UnprocessedAccounts with no other description.
ive checked and they're both in the same region and the accounts are unrelated

```
    creation_response = client.create_members(AccountDetails=[
        {
            'AccountId': account_id,
            'Email': email
        }
    ])
```

Comment: can you add your code in your question ?

Comment: sure. ive updated the question

Comment: can you add the value inside UnprocessedAccounts  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with aws support I realized that the member I am trying to create is the account thats making the request.